# EACCES Spawn Error Ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, mobile, ionic2

I'm writing because I'm facing off a problem since a week and I'm having trouble fixing it. I hope to receive some help. Thanks in advice.

This is the situation. I'm developing an application using Ionic 2 Framework on my Mac. I always get this error when I try to run the app on Android/iOS or when I try to simply build it:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/manu/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: spawn EACCES

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

I tried to run commands like these:

```
sudo chmod -777 /Users/manu/Library/Android/sdk
```

or

```
sudo chmod -775 /Users/manu/Library/Android/sdk
```

Over both directories but nothing happened.

This is my first project using Ionic 2, maybe I am missing something stupid...

Thanks in advice for your precious time.

EDIT

Trying to update CLI I got this:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@9.2.0 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ ionic@3.19.0
added 124 packages, removed 1 package and updated 11 packages in 20.936s
iMac-di-Manuel:/ manu$
```

Comment: I saw that post but that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you adapt the path according to your actual installation?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/grad
le/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle`  In this command you would have to put the actual gradle version number that you use.

Comment: I don't have that /Applications/Android folder... I am missing something I think, forgive me... If I do ls -l in /Applications folder I only get "Chrome Apps.localized" and nothing else.

Comment: Well I'm sorry I can't help. Last idea: update Ionic CLI, android studio, etc.

Comment: I got error during update too... See the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I tried to do the following command before

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.2.1/bin/gradle
```

I made a mistake, I changed the Gradle's version and then it worked. I used

```
sudo chmod 777
```

instead of 755, but the result was the same. Thanks to Sébastien for the help.